# Bad CentOS server performance with Digium T1/E1 TDM Card

Tags: centos, telephony

I have a PowerEdge 2850 server that used to work well under CentOS 5 i386. It was used with Asterisk as a telephony server, hooked up to the world via a T1 line.

I've since wiped it and installed CentOS 6 x86_64, and everything works well as long as you boot from the install media. As soon as you reboot from the installed image, things slow down to a crawl. It takes about a second for every letter typed on the local console to appear on screen. SSH access through the network is abysmally slow as well. Hard drive read speeds are around 0.5mbytes/s. Same thing happens on CentOS 6 i386. Updating the system using yum doesn't help.

A T1 line from a Cisco router is plugged into the T1/E1 card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the default CentOS configuration loads the netjet driver for the Digium card, and that driver is the root of the problem. **This driver is not the right driver, it doesn't make any sense to use it with Digium telephony cards.** As soon as you rmmod the driver, the system's performance recovers. One can turn the driver off in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` by adding the following line:

```
blacklist netjet
```

To use the card, you'll need to install dahdi-linux with appropriate driver package, and configure it for your card.